# Custom authentication via SOAP webservice using ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

I am trying to implement Custom authentication via SOAP webservice

as per Refering links

http://it-cook-de.blogspot.in/2013/07/zend-framework-2-custom-authentication-with-soap-webservice-part-1.html
http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/23/zend-framework-2-create-login-authentication-using-authenticationservice-with-rememberme/#comment-6117

Now getting error as
[image]

Code :

```
<?php
namespace Application\Adapter;

use Zend\Authentication\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Authentication\Result;
use Zend\Soap\Client;
use Zend\Soap\Client\DotNet as DotNet;

class SoapAuthenticationAdapter implements AdapterInterface
{
 //:TODO: move to configuration
    //private $module = 'my_application_name_in_auth_system';
      private $module = 'student';
 //:TODO: move to configuration
   // private $uri = 'full_url_to_soap_webservice_of_auth_system';
      private $uri = 'http://ip/Service/student.svc?wsdl';
 //:TODO: move to configuration
    //private $location = 'full_url_to_soap_webservice_of_auth_system';
    private $location = 'http://ip/Service/student.svc?wsdl';

    protected $username;

    protected $password;

    protected  $customercode;

    function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function authenticate()
    {

            $client = new DotNet($this->uri);
            $param=array("customercode"=>$this->customercode,"username"=>$this->username,"password"=>$this->password);

            $result = $client->call('ValidateUser',array($param));
           if ($result) {
                $this->permissions = $param;
                return $this->getResult(Result::SUCCESS, $this->permissions, 'SUCCESS');
            } else {
                return $this->getResult(Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID, null, 'FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID');
            }
        } catch (\SoapFault $e) {
           // switch ($e->getMessage()) {
                return $this->getResult(Result::FAILURE_UNCATEGORIZED, null, $e->getMessage());
           // }
        }
    }

   public function setIdentity($username)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public  function setCredential($password)
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    public function  setCustomerCode($customercode)
    {
        $this->customercode =$customercode;
    }
    private function getResult($type, $identity, $message)
    {
        return new Result($type, $identity, array(
            $message
        ));
    }
}
/////In IndexController
public function getAuthService()
    {
        if (! $this->authservice) {
            $this->authservice = $this->getServiceLocator()
            ->get('SoapAuthenticationService');
        }

        return $this->authservice;
    }

        public function someAction()
        {
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        if ($request->isPost()){
            $this->getAuthService()->getAdapter()
            ->setIdentity($request->getPost('username'))
            ->setCredential($request->getPost('password'))
            ->setCustomerCode($request->getPost('customercode'));
            $result = $this->getAuthService()->authenticate();
            foreach($result->getMessages() as $message)
                {
                    //save message temporary into flashmessenger
                    $this->flashmessenger()->addMessage($message);
                }

                if ($result->isValid()) {
                    $redirect = 'home';
                    //check if it has rememberMe :
                    if ($request->getPost('rememberme') == 1 ) {
                        $this->getSessionStorage()
                        ->setRememberMe(1);
                        //set storage again
                        $this->getAuthService()->setStorage($this->getSessionStorage());
                    }
                    $this->getAuthService()->setStorage($this->getSessionStorage());
                    $this->getAuthService()->getStorage()->write($request->getPost('username'));
                }
                else
                {
                    $redirect ='login';
        }

        return $this->redirect()->toRoute($redirect);
    }
```

in module.php

```
 public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'factories' => array(
    //Add the following lines
    'Application\Model\SoapAuthenticationStorage' => function($sm){
                 return new SoapAuthenticationStorage('student');
                },
                'SoapAuthenticationService' => function($sm) {
                 $authAdapter  = new SoapAuthenticationAdapter();
                  $authService = new AuthenticationService();
                 $authService->setAdapter($authAdapter);
                   $authService->setStorage($sm->get('Application\Model\SoapAuthenticationStorage'));
                 return $authService;
                }
   )
  );
 }
```

Any help to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the set methods in your adapter need to return `$this` in order to allow you to chain method calls together (this is called a 'fluent interface'). E.g.:

```
public function setIdentity($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}
```

That should fix the error you're getting.

Comment: how can we get the post data inside the authentication(). after setIdentity(), tried to access through $this->username, but is giving blank? as per the above code

Comment: `$this->username` should work based on your code. Will need some more context if that's not working - how and where are you calling that?

Comment: As per the above code, when i call authentication function(which is in class SoapAuthentication Adapter) from my Controller i need to get the username and password inside that function adapter. Even after triggering the setIdentity() from controller the username is not getting set. Whether it is initializing a  new object?

Comment: Sorry i did the mistake i my form itself , now issue solved everything working fine